# Вопрос по асинхронным запросам в C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго времени суток! Меня интересует тема "Асинхронные запросы в С #." Хотелось бы узнать немного теории о данной теме (теорию применимую к практике) и примеры к коду:

```
private string GetString(string url)
{
    var basic = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("esmirnov:111103"));
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basic);
    return client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
}
```

Мне нужно сделать асинхронный запрос из этого кода

```
var basic = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("esmirn:11110"));
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basic);
client.DeleteAsync($"http://localhost:8080/Product?id={id}").Result;
```

Спасибо тем, кто поможет решить эту задачу

Comment: достаточно убрать `.Result` и перед вызовом поставить `await`

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Да ,немного удалось ,но можно вас спросить .Для чего нужны асинхронные запросы ,и как сделать асинхронный запрос к базе данных MYSGL

Comment: Можете поделиться информацией  про асинхронные вопросы

Comment: Для работы с базами есть Entity Framework. Для чего нужны - вопрос из разряда "зачем надо программировать?", такой же неконкретный. Я не знаю, для чего вам асинхронные запросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно создавать клиент на каждый запрос, это медленно и может при частых запросах привести к сбоям связи.

Создавайте клиент 1 раз

```
private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Заголовки по умолчанию вынесите в конструктор класса. Так как вы не показали код самого класса, я не знаю, как оформить этот участок кода.

Заголовок авторизации не следует выносить в `DefaultRequestHeaders`, так как он требуется не для всех запросов, верно?

Вот вам асинхронный код.

```
private async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url, string user, string password)
{
    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{user}:{password}"));
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);
    using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

- [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async)
- [IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)
- [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ ,я не ожидал получить такого быстрого ответа. А как писать код если там не используется токен

Comment: @Илья Ну напишите еще один метод, где нет токена. Удалить 2 строчки из этого кода вы же сможете?

Comment: да я об этом и думал ,спасибо за ответ